# Zend Expresive - EmitterException: Output has been emitted previously

Tags: php, nginx, zend-framework, mezzio

I was trying to configure my website on VPS. On my local machine everything works fine, but on VPS I got 500 error. This is log:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Exception\EmitterException: Output has been emitted previously; cannot emit response in /var/www/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner/src/Exception/EmitterException.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner/src/Emitter/SapiEmitterTrait.php(33): Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Exception\EmitterException::forOutputSent()
#1 /var/www/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner/src/Emitter/SapiEmitter.php(26): Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter->assertNoPreviousOutput()
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner/src/Emitter/EmitterStack.php(40): Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter->emit(Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response\HtmlResponse))
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner/src/RequestHandlerRunner.php(97): Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\EmitterStack->emit(Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response\HtmlResponse))
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/zendfram" while reading response header from upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "***.***.***.***:***"
```

I'm using:

- Zend Expresive 3
- Nginx 1.14.0
- PHP 7.2 FPM

I have not idea what cause the problem and it is hard for me to debug it on this server.

Comment: I have the same problem, no ideia

Answer (score 1):

Check your code. First turn off emitter. And whatch what part of code send response firstly. Most probably it does some error like wrong connection to db. Also it can be `var_dump` or `echo` command which print message erlier then emmiter.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when, I wrote it wrong the database name in the `database.global.php` file. I fixed the configuration, and works.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have an error in the view that you're attempting to render.